# Adding a root to a route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a lot of routes defined like so:

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/user/find', {
       templateUrl: '/partials/login.html'
    });
```

How do I dynamically add something to my routes, so it will be (for example)

`.when('myroot/user/find'`

Of course, I could use a variable add do a `myvar+'user/find'` but that leads to a lot of duplication (especially if I have a lot of routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend this, but you can try patching `$routeProvider.when` to add the string for you:

```
...

$routeProvider.__when = $routeProvider.when;

$routeProvider.when = function(url, route){
    this.__when('/myroot' + url, route);
};

...
```

But as said before, I do not recommend this, because:

- it could not work in future version of Angularjs
- you're code become less clear
- you are not more able to bind on url that doesn't start with `myroot`

What I recommend is to through your code and edit each route manually...